# How to avoid violating the DRY principle when the boolean expression of a while loop is reassigned every loop pass?

Tags: while-loop, coding-style, pascal, lazarus, freepascal

Both

```
while MyFunction(1, 2, 3) > 0 do
  begin
    Temp := MyFunction(1, 2, 3);
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Temp));
  end;
```

and

```
Temp := MyFunction(1, 2, 3);
while Temp > 0 do
  begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Temp));
    Temp := MyFunction(1, 2, 3);
  end;
```

violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) because there are two calls to `MyFunction` when only one is necessary.

Comment: You original version is fine. And this question is subjective and so not valid here.

Comment: Read the [help]. This is a classic primarily opinion based close candidate.

Comment: You can avoid loops at all using old good `goto` operator by the way ;o)

Comment: In my opinion the `while True` variant is better. You prefer different variants. Which one of us is objectively right? Neither, because it comes down to judgement and opinion. Hence this question should be closed as being "primarily opinion based".

Comment: That's off topic also. That's a [list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98334/list-questions-community-wiki) question. Please delete this question. And then use the `while True` variant which is the idiomatic way to write this code. You are fighting against the lanaguage rather than trying to fit in with it. Don't swim against the tide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy,

```
  function dotemp(a,b,c:integer;var value : integer):boolean;
  begin
    value:a*b+c;
    result:=value>0; 
  end;

  begin
    while dotemp(a,b,c,temp) do
        begin
           Operateontemp(temp);
         end;
  end;
```

Pascal has no lvalue assignments, but it DOES have var parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see the problem. Why don't you invert the logic and forget about Break:

```
repeat
  Temp := MyFunction(1, 2, 3);
  if Temp <= 0 then
  begin
    //code which uses Temp, for example:
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Temp));
  end;
until Temp > 0;
```

That does exactly the same as you first sample, i.e. the `while True do` code snippet, but neither calls the function twice, nor does it need to use an assignment as an expression (not possible in Delphi), nor does it need to exit early with Break.

In C, you would do this with

```
do
{
    ...
} while (temp <= 0);
```

Note that every

```
if (condition) then 
  Break;
```

can be replaced by

```
if not (condition) then
  // rest of original loop.
end;
```

for the rest of the loop.

Comment: There's duplication. The test of Temp is performed twice. Better to store result in a local book or use while True and break, a respectable idiom.

Comment: I don't think that using Break is better. And testing a variable twice is no big deal.

Comment: It's a violation of DRY as written in your answer. Which is what can be avoided by the two methods I offered. Still, I don't understand why we are answering opinion based questions. They should be closed. Did you vote to close?

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility to use an infinite loop and `Break`:

```
while True do
  begin
    Temp := MyFunction(1, 2, 3);
    if Temp <= 0 then Break;
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Temp));
  end;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Temp := 1;
while Temp > 0 do
begin
   //...
end;
```

Or repeat-until